# A finite-codimensional subspace of the space of [square-integrable] holomorphic functions

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, holomorphic-functions

Here is a claim I found in the proof of lemma 14.3 of Otto Forster's Lectures on Riemann Surfaces. I can't see how this claim is true, and Forster does not explain it. Help please! I have distilled my question down to its basics, i.e. I have removed all other information in the lemma that doesn't pertain to my specific question. Here it is:

Say $D$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Let $a_1,...a_n$ be a finite set of points and let $r>0$ be such that $B(a_j,r) \subset D$ for $j=1,\dots, n$. Denote by $L^2(D,\mathcal{O})$ the space of square integrable holomorphic functions on $D$, i.e. holomorphic functions on $D$ for which 
$$\iint_D |f(x+iy)|^2 \,dx\,dy < \infty$$

The claim is that, if $A \subset L^2(D, \mathcal{O})$ is the subspace of square-integrable holomorphic functions which vanish at all points $a_j$ to at least order $k$, then $A$ has codimension $\leq kn$.

How?? I am finding it difficult to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple. Define $T:L^2(D,\mathcal O)\to\Bbb C^{n\times k}$ by $$Tf_{j,\alpha}=f^{(\alpha)}(a_j),\quad(1\le j\le n, 0\le\alpha<k).$$Then $A$ is the kernel  of $T$.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I have forgotten some piece of elementary linear algebra, but why would the kernel of $T$ need to have finite codimension? Is there some theorem? I'm with you so far, but I can't see how $ker(T)$ must have finite condimension, that's all...

Comment: The codimension of $W$ in $V$ is the dimension of the quotient $V/W$, right? And if $T$ is linear then $V/\ker(T)$ is isomorphic to the range of $T$...

Comment: Okay that's very clear. Thank you.